# how to store two different record type data i one list?

Tags: apex, record-type, for-update

i have to add records of different records types in one list and upsert the same list
how can i add records of different record type and upsert it

```
 List<fit__c> listToUpsert = new List<fit__c>();
        String sContentVersionId;
      if(fitResponse.document != null && !fitResponse.document.isEmpty() &&  fitResponse.document[0].data != null && fitResponse.document[0].data.plan != null && !fitResponse.document[0].data.plan.isEmpty()){
            fit__c fitRecord;
            Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> mapfitRecordTypes = Schema.SObjectType.fit__c.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName(); 
            sContentVersionId = fitResponse.document[0].id;

            for(fitResponseWrapper.fitPlan fitPlan : fitResponse.document[0].data.plan){
                fitRecord = new fit__c(fit_JSON_Response__c = sNLPFileResponse);
                if(fitPlan.administration != null && fitPlan.administration.administrationSection != null && !fitPlan.administration.administrationSection.isEmpty()){
                    fitRecord = persistAdministrationData(fitRecord,
                                                              Plan.administration);
                }

                if(fitPlan.medical != null && ((fitPlan.medical.generalBasisOfAdministration != null && fitPlan.medical.generalBasisOfAdministration.generalfit != null && !fitPlan.medical.generalBasisOfAdministration.generalfit.isEmpty())|| (fitPlan.medical.fits != null && fitPlan.medical.fits.fitCategory != null &&  !fitPlan.medical.fits.fitCategory.isEmpty()))){
                    fitRecord = persistMedicalData(fitRecord,fitPlan.medical);

                    fitRecord.RecordTypeId = mapfitRecordTypes.containsKey(StaticVariableClass.FIT_MEDICAL_RT_NAME) ? mapfitRecordTypes.get(StaticVariableClass.FIT_MEDICAL_RT_NAME).getRecordTypeId() : null;
                } 
                if(fitPlan.vision != null && ((fitPlan.vision.generalBasisOfAdministration != null && fitPlan.vision.generalBasisOfAdministration.generalfit != null && !fitPlan.vision.generalBasisOfAdministration.generalfit.isEmpty())|| (fitPlan.vision.fits != null && fitPlan.vision.fits.fitCategory != null &&  !fitPlan.vision.fits.fitCategory.isEmpty()))){
                    if(fitRecord.RecordTypeId == null){
                        fitRecord = persistVisionData(fitRecord,fitPlan.vision);

                    fitRecord.RecordTypeId = mapfitRecordTypes.containsKey(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME) ? mapfitRecordTypes.get(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME).getRecordTypeId() : null;
                    }
                    else{
                        fit__c oVisionfit =  fitRecord.clone();
                        oVisionfit = persistVisionData(oVisionfit,ofitPlan.vision);
                        oVisionfit.RecordTypeId = mapfitRecordTypes.containsKey(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME) ? mapfitRecordTypes.get(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME).getRecordTypeId() : null;

                    }
                }
                listToUpsert.add(fitRecord);
            }
```

now in listtoupsert 
how can i store both of the records

Answer (score 0):

Since they are both `fit__c` records (based on your code you just add them both to the list:

```
else{
                        fit__c oVisionfit =  fitRecord.clone();
                        oVisionfit = persistVisionData(oVisionfit,ofitPlan.vision);
                        oVisionfit.RecordTypeId = mapfitRecordTypes.containsKey(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME) ? mapfitRecordTypes.get(StaticVariableClass.FIT_VISION_RT_NAME).getRecordTypeId() : null;
                        ****listToUpsert.add(oVisionFit);****
                    }
                }
                listToUpsert.add(fitRecord);
```

Comment: if i do upsert for vision , what if  i have to upsert both of the record types records

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. They are both the same Subject type and even if they were not you could upset them both in one list if you made the list an Object lists but this has other considerations you need to be aware of

Comment: You might need to do a DEEPCLONE of the fitRecord though so you can set the record type without change the original fitRecord

Comment: That does not matter one bit. Recordtype are just a field value